# How to Get All Rows matched + Unmatched and Unmatched Rows Column Will be null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an university management system. This is my database diagram

[Database Diagram](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eofk7s9l1qfrknf/Untitled.jpg?m=)

I am creating a search form using this query:

```
SELECT Distinct    
   TblStudentBioData.RegNo, 
   TblStudentBioData.First_NameUr + SPACE(1)+ TblStudentBioData.Middle_NameUr + SPACE(1) + TblStudentBioData.Last_NameUr AS Name,                                   
   TblStudentBioData.Father_NameUr, 
   Ay.AcademicYearName, 
   Smst.SemName, 
   TBLCOLLEGE.CollegeName,  
   CID.ClassName, 
   TblImages.Images,
   TblStudentBioData.Student_ID,
   TblImages.ImageId,
   Ay.AcademicYearId, 
   Smst.SemesterId,
   TblClassSchedule.ClassSchId        
FROM  
   TblStudentBioData 
LEFT JOIN
   TblStudentDetail ON (TblStudentBioData.Student_ID = TblStudentDetail.Student_ID) 
                      OR (TblStudentBioData.Student_ID != TblStudentDetail.Student_ID)
INNER JOIN
   TBLCFGSEX AS sex ON TblStudentBioData.CfgSexId = sex.CfgSexId 
INNER JOIN
   TBLMARITALSTATUS ON TblStudentBioData.MaritalStatusId = TBLMARITALSTATUS.MaritalStatusId 
INNER JOIN  
   TblStudentSubAss ON TblStudentDetail.StudentDetailID = TblStudentSubAss.StudentDetailID 
INNER JOIN
   TblSubAss ON TblSubAss.SubAssId = TblStudentSubAss.SubAssId 
INNER JOIN 
   TblClassSchedule ON TblStudentDetail.ClassSchId = TblClassSchedule.ClassSchID 
INNER JOIN
   TableClass AS CID ON  TblClassSchedule.ClassID = CID.ClassID 
INNER JOIN
   TblImages ON TblStudentBioData.ImageId = TblImages.ImageId 
LEFT JOIN
   TBLCOLLEGE ON CID.CollegeId = TBLCOLLEGE.CollegeID 
INNER JOIN
   TBLBLOODGROUP BG On TblStudentBioData.BloodID = BG.BloodId 
INNER JOIN
   tableSemAssigning SA On TblClassSchedule.SemAssId = Sa.SemAssId 
INNER JOIN
   TblAcademicYear AY On SA.AcademicYearId = AY.AcademicYearId   
INNER JOIN
   TableSemester Smst On Smst.SemesterId = Sa.SemesterId
```

and this query gives me the output like this

[image]

In the result the 5th row is not matching row.

My question: how to show null value in non matching row's columns which I mention in the image?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with the first listed join (a left join) `ON (TblStudentBioData.Student_ID = TblStudentDetail.Student_ID) OR (TblStudentBioData.Student_ID != TblStudentDetail.Student_ID)` why join when equal or when NOT equal?

Comment: i want to get matching and unmatching records

Comment: that is a really bizarre way of doing this, it becomes a cross join, and I don't think you can rely on this query at all. remove the second part of that left join (the not equals condition) and try again.

Comment: After Removing Second part of the left join it is returning only matched rows Which is currently above 4 rows....

Comment: try using only left joins

Comment: @user2067753 is right. That way you get a Cartesian product of two tables. removing the `!=` condition is correct. Now the `INNER JOIN`s after that left join prevent the unmatching rows being included in the result. Change them to left join

Comment: sorry, try using only left joins to anything that relies on TblStudentDetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell it would be like this. Anything that relates directly to TblStudentBioData MIGHT be an an INNER JOIN (I cannot tell) but everything that relates to TblStudentDetail should be a left join.

Also be careful with any where clause that you don't override these left joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT /* I hate distinct, there is probably a better way */

      TblStudentBioData.RegNo
    , TblStudentBioData.First_NameUr + SPACE(1) + TblStudentBioData.Middle_NameUr + SPACE(1) + TblStudentBioData.Last_NameUr AS Name
    , TblStudentBioData.Father_NameUr
    , Ay.AcademicYearName
    , Smst.SemName
    , TBLCOLLEGE.CollegeName
    , CID.ClassName
    , TblImages.Images
    , TblStudentBioData.Student_ID
    , TblImages.ImageId
    , Ay.AcademicYearId
    , Smst.SemesterId
    , TblClassSchedule.ClassSchId
FROM TblStudentBioData
      INNER JOIN TBLCFGSEX AS sex
                  ON TblStudentBioData.CfgSexId = sex.CfgSexId
      INNER JOIN TBLMARITALSTATUS
                  ON TblStudentBioData.MaritalStatusId = TBLMARITALSTATUS.MaritalStatusId
      INNER JOIN TblImages
                  ON TblStudentBioData.ImageId = TblImages.ImageId
      INNER JOIN TBLBLOODGROUP BG
                  ON TblStudentBioData.BloodID = BG.BloodId

      LEFT JOIN TblStudentDetail
                  ON (TblStudentBioData.Student_ID = TblStudentDetail.Student_ID)
      LEFT JOIN TblStudentSubAss
                  ON TblStudentDetail.StudentDetailID = TblStudentSubAss.StudentDetailID
      LEFT JOIN TblClassSchedule
                  ON TblStudentDetail.ClassSchId = TblClassSchedule.ClassSchID

      LEFT JOIN TblSubAss
                  ON TblSubAss.SubAssId = TblStudentSubAss.SubAssId
      LEFT JOIN TableClass AS CID
                  ON TblClassSchedule.ClassID = CID.ClassID
      LEFT JOIN TBLCOLLEGE
                  ON CID.CollegeId = TBLCOLLEGE.CollegeID
      LEFT JOIN tableSemAssigning SA
                  ON TblClassSchedule.SemAssId = SA.SemAssId
      LEFT JOIN TblAcademicYear AY
                  ON SA.AcademicYearId = AY.AcademicYearId
      LEFT JOIN TableSemester Smst
                  ON Smst.SemesterId = SA.SemesterId
```

Comment: Which is the best way instead using distinct ?

Comment: Which is the best way instead using distinct? The reason you need `select distinct` most probably comes from one (or more) of the joins involving a many-to-one relationship. The `best way` is to reduce that join to a one-to-one relationship. Try these http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2006/03/14/9289.aspx

http://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/07/24/the-effects-of-distinct-in-a-sql-query/

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx